# Unable to open JavaScript files in Eclipse Luna (Windows 7)

Tags: javascript

Whenever I attempt to open any javascript files of my project, it gives a popup  message saying:

> script : "D:/.../file.js
>  Error : Expected identified, string or
>   number
>  Code : 800A0404
>  Source : Microsoft JScript compilation
>   error.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if you have not registered Windows to open javascript files with an application. Use the following steps to enable Eclipse to open javascript files when they are opened from Windows Explorer:

1. Right click on the javascript file.
2. Expand the "Open With" menu.
3. Click "Choose default application".
4. Click "Browse".
5. Select the Eclipse executable.
6. Check "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file"
7. Click OK.

Now Windows should open Eclipse by default when a javascript file is opened.